# $H$ very ample, $f$ finite, is there uniform $C=C(\mathrm{deg}(f))$ for $C f^* H$ very ample?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, divisors, line-bundles, ample-bundles, pullback

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normal projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension $n$. Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ be a finite morphism. Also, let $H$ be a very ample divisor on $Y$.

Is there a constant $C=C(\mathrm{deg}(f),n)$ depending just on degree and dimension such that $Cf^*H$ is very ample? If the answer is in general no, are there natural conditions to impose?

Comment: What do you fix?? If you want a universal $C$ depending only on $\deg(f)$, this doesn't exist already for $\deg(f)=2$.

Comment: @abx I am fixing the degree and the dimension. I forgot to include the dimension in the statement. Is it still not enough?

Comment: No, it is not enough — already with degree 2 and dimension 1.

Comment: @abx Thank you for the reply. Are there conditions on the ramification that one could put to get such a statement?

Comment: Well, some kind of bound on the ramification would eliminate the counter-examples that I have in mind. But I have no idea of what would be a reasonable formulation.

Comment: @abx I see. Thank you for all the comments. I wil try to think about the last one

Comment: Since $f^*H$ is ample and gg, then $K_X+(dim X+1)f^*H $ is gg (and something similar will be very ample)...But to answer your question you would need to control when $cf^*H-K_X$ is nef (in abx's example, if $f_*O_X=O_Y\oplus (-tH)$, and say $K_Y=0$, then $c\geq t$ can be arbitrarily big). Maybe one can show something similar with $K_{X/Y}$ instead of $K_X$, but I doubt you can do any better.